# How to Construct a matrix with requisite properties or how to show why no such matrix exists?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Construct a matrix  with requisite properties or why no such matrix exists.

The null space and column space both have the basis \begin{bmatrix}
1
\\ 0
\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}

By rank nullity theorem rank of this matrix will be 1 and nullity is 1 and so the number of column is this matrix will be 2 and since rank of this matrix is 1 then the other column is the scalar multiple of \begin{bmatrix}
1
\\ 0
\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}

But no such matrix exists since the number of column of this matrix is not equal to 3. But I am not sure about my reasoning. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is good. Think of it this way: If the column space and the null space are to have the same basis, they have to be subspaces of the same vector space, which forces the matrix to be square (see why)? Now, since the particular basis in question consists of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we are talking about a $3 \times 3$ matrix. However, as you point out, by the rank-nullity theorem, the number of columns would have to be 2, which is a contradiction.